# Where is timerID coming from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm halfway to understanding how `this.timerId` doesn't cause an error in the react docs.

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {    this.setState({      date: new Date()    });  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I get that `timerId` along with `setInterval` come from Node. I thought node was just the runtime, does it come with other modules aside from Node Timers?  Where is `timerID` initialized and or inherited from? Do all objects get a `timerID` when running on Node?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: _"come from Node"_ - I don't think so. Since the code looks to run in the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: “Where is timerID initialized and or inherited from?” -, `this.timeId = something` is an assignment. That’s pretty fundamental to how most programming langages work and is in the code you shared.

Comment: Do all objects [no, not all obejcts] get a timerID [nothing "gets" a timerID per se] when running on Node [this is unrelated to node, both the code and in general]

Comment: Thanks for the response Quentin, I'm coming from java. It's unfamiliar to me to be able to set new state on an object after it's been created. I don't see timeId in the constructor. Am I confused because of javascript syntax maybe? How can timeId be set on ```this``` when it wasn't initialized during construction?

Comment: How can timeId be set on this when it wasn't initialized during construction? - It just *can*, that is how javascript works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.timerID in this case is created as a new property at the point that it is assigned a Value, as pointed out by @luk2302 in the comments.

Below shows another possible way you could refer to a property that wasn't created in that class directly, but in the parent class.

```
class SuperClass {
    constructor() {
        this.superProperty = "Hello I'm super!"
    }
}

class SupportClass extends SuperClass{
    constructor(example) {
        super();
        this.example = example;
    }

    supportMethod() {
        console.log(this.example);
        console.log(this.superProperty);
    }

}

let supportClass = new SupportClass("HELLO");

supportClass.supportMethod();
```

this produces an output:

```
HELLO
Hello I'm super!
```

Comment: Thank you Craig. This is all I was looking for.

Comment: No, `timerID` is not from `React.Component`. Can you point to a doc to support that claim? You can simply create new properties outside the constructor wherever and whenever you want. This answer is wrong @bdehmer , see e.g. `class P{constructor(){this.a=2;}something(){this.b=1;}}p=new P();p.something();p.b`

Comment: It seems like your right and i've made an incorrect assumption. I'll change my answer to reflect your comments.